# Add text to multiple .txt files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder with thousands of text files, and I need to convert them all (Which I already know how to do). Before doing any of that though I need to add HTML code before and after whatever is in the text file. Example is below

```
<HTML><HEAD><META content="IE=5.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 11.00.10586.1045"></HEAD>
<BODY><PRE> 
TEXT FILE CONTENT GOES HERE
</PRE></BODY></HTML>
```

Is there anyway to do this? I know I am able to run a loop in cmd prompt, but I only have enough knowledge to the extent of merging multiple files, and not actually adding text.

Comment: put the text to add (it's static, right?) to a `before.txt` and an `after.txt`and merge them with every of your "thousands of files".

Comment: You could put the top part in head.dat, the bottom part in tail.dat, and `for %I in (*.txt) copy head.dat+"%I"+tail.dat "%~nI-fixed.txt"` or similar.  See `copy /?` for an explanation of the `+` operator in copy operations.

Comment: Thanks rojo. left out the "do" in the loop, but after I added that it is working wonderfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete batch code based for this task.

The header and footer file can be configured at top of the batch file. The batch file automatically creates and deletes the header and footer files if not existing already on running the batch file.

All *.txt files in current directory are merged together with the header and footer file to *.html files using command **COPY** with three source files being specified with `+` operator. An existing *.html file in current directory with same name as a *.txt file is overwritten except read-only attribute is set on existing HTML file or current NTFS permissions or file sharing access permissions do not grant overwriting existing HTML file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "HeaderFile=%TEMP%\Header.tmp"
set "FooterFile=%TEMP%\Footer.tmp"
set "DeleteHeaderFile="
set "DeleteFooterFile="

if not exist "%HeaderFile%" (
    set "DeleteHeaderFile=1"
    echo ^<HTML^>^<HEAD^>^<META content="IE=5.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"^>
    echo ^<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type^>
    echo ^<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 11.00.10586.1045"^>^</HEAD^>
    echo ^<BODY^>^<PRE^>
) >"%HeaderFile%"

if not exist "%FooterFile%" (
    set "DeleteFooterFile=1"
    echo ^</PRE^>^</BODY^>^</HTML^>>"%FooterFile%"
)

for %%I in (*.txt) do copy /B "%HeaderFile%"+"%%I"+"%FooterFile%" "%%~nI.html" >nul

if defined DeleteHeaderFile del "%HeaderFile%"
if defined DeleteFooterFile del "%FooterFile%"
endlocal
```

The **COPY** option `/B` for interpreting the files as binary files prevents appending control character [substitute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) at end of generated HTML file.

Please note that **FOR** ignores *.txt files with hidden attribute set.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Sorry to bump this back up, but I was wondering how I can alter this to save the files in the directories that they were found in? I've changed the line to for /R %%I in (*.txt) do copy /B "%HeaderFile%"+"%%I"+"%FooterFile%" "%%~nI.html" >nul but it converts them and puts them in the directory with the batch file. How do I make it put them in the original folder?

Comment: @Xiodrade Replace `"%%~nI.html"` – just file name without file path and file extension with `.html` appended – to `"%%~dpnI.html"` – drive and path and file name without file extension with `.html` appended. The possible modifiers before the loop variable `I` are explained by the help output on running `for /?` in a command prompt window. By using __FOR__ option `/R` for a recursive search the string assigned to loop variable `I` is not anymore just file name with file extension, but file name with file extension and with complete path.

Comment: Thanks this works. I didn't realize what dpn stood for, but now I do!